# Обработка ASCII-символов регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c++

Имеится сырой массив unsigned char, набитый разными символами [0; 255].

Нужно найти и извлечь некоторую строку "01", заданую регулярным виражением. Код вроде выглядит рабочим, но блок if почему-то проскакивает. Не могу никак понять, в чем проблема.

```
stringstream rawString;

for (unsigned char i=0; i<255; i++) {
    rawString << i;
}

regex pattern("[\\x00-\\xff]*(01)[\\x00-\\xff]*", regex_constants::egrep);
smatch result;

if ( regex_match( rawString.str(), result, pattern ) ) {
    cout << result[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unsigned char rawString[256];

for (int i=0; i<256; i++) {
    rawString[i] = i;
}

string str(rawString, rawString + sizeof(rawString));

regex pattern("^([^\\x00]|[\\x00])*(01)([^\\x00]|[\\x00])*$");
smatch result;

if ( regex_match( str, result, pattern ) ) {
    cout << result[2];
}
```